# A WYSIWYG text editor for iPhone Safari?

Tags: iphone, tinymce, text-editor, wysiwyg, touch

After a few tests with my iPhone on various sites (a few Django one etc) I was looking at WYSIWYG editors and realised they don't really work too well on small touch screen devices such as the iPhone. Infact, TinyMCE (which I use for most Django projects) just doesn't really work at all.

So I'm curious, is there a solution out there will allow simple text editing functions for text boxes that work on iPhone Safari? ...even just simple stuff as bold, italic, lists etc. Or would I have to come up with my own?

Thanks for any information and light on this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear you will have to do it yourself, because all browser versions for the iphone are pretty stripped down in functionality (that is why TinyMCE does not work).

Comment: I thought as much. I was thinking about it and because of the way the popup keyboard comes up, it doesn't seem to me it would work... Thanks.

Comment: Well, i heard there is another new phone on the market that supports full javascripting and therefor TinyMce and other RTEs.

Comment: Thariama, do you know if this is the case now?  Is anyone having any luck implementing tinymce on any popular/current mobile device?

Comment: this is not the case anymore, using the latest iOS and modifying the own CMS code makes it possible to get a wysiwyg editor like tinymce to run

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research myself on this issue, WYSIWYGs are terrible on Mobile Safari across the board due to a lack of features in the browser.

See this thread in CLEditor discussing the issue:
http://groups.google.com/group/cleditor/browse_thread/thread/bc64062dae8a22dc

That being said, using CLEditor you at least get a usable textarea on Mobile Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Safari's HTML 5 implementation doesn't support the `contenteditable` attribute, so the majority of the better WYSIWYG rich text editors (TinyMCE, FCKEditor, YUI's RTE) are disabled on the iPad and other iOS devices for now. Frustrating, for sure.

Comment: *Note:* the latest TinyMCE release does support iOS5 properly now. I think [v3.5](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=28724) is the latest.